# C#: JSON Schema validation and JSON.stringify

Tags: c#, validation, .net-3.5, json.net, jsonschema

[Sorry for my horrible english]

Now I use JSON.Net, but it is too strict validation to a numeric type.
The catch is that JSON.stringify sees no difference between "number" and "integer", there is only "number" for him.
It turns out that if you serialize 1.0, the output will simply 1 (integer), while JSON.Net Validator will be expected "number".

I do not want to assign a "number" in the "int", I want to assign the "integer" in the "float".
Example schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "singleField": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
  "singleField":1//it is 1.0 after JSON.stringify
}
```

Validation will be failed.

The most appropriate solution would be to use the schema on the client, but does not have such a possibility.
I'm not tied to JSON.Net, so to make any decisions.
I use .net 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is in old version of JSON.Net. This code works:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Generation;

public class JSSchemaTest
{
    class TestClass
    {
        public float field = 20;
    }
    JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public void Run()
    {
        JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(TestClass));
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader("{field: 2}"));
        JSchemaValidatingReader validatingReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader(reader);
        validatingReader.Schema = schema;
        TestClass res = serializer.Deserialize<TestClass>(validatingReader);
    }
}
```

Used Json.NET 8.0.2, Json.NET Schema 2.0.2.

**UPD**: As alternative, in old versions of JSON.Net we can make small modify in file JsonSchemaGenerator. Search this line:

```
internal static bool HasFlag(JsonSchemaType? value, JsonSchemaType flag)
```

And replace its "return" to own:

```
return (flag == JsonSchemaType.Integer && value == JsonSchemaType.Float) ? true : ((value & flag) == flag);
```